# C# WP10 Page is not resizing after Hide Status Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I am currently making a for windows phone, in the app I am trying to hide the status bar, it works fine, as it should on windows phone 8.1 but on windows phone 10 i get some weird results.

here is the XAML im using

```
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas"          
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Background="Black"
        Height="Auto">
```

like i said it works in every emulator/actual devices 8.1 and not on any windows 10 phones

as shown in the image below here is what i have tried

- if i don't hide the status bar it loads fine
- if i do hide the status bar the whole page shifts up and leaves a gap
- if i set the canvas height by code to

  canvas.height = window.current.bounds.height

the whole app falls behind the commandbar.

- if i set the canvas height by code to

  canvas.height = (window.current.bounds.height - CBar.height)

i get the same as the first issue

both times the gap has appeared it is the same height as the commandbar when it is expanded (tapped on)

so is this a

- command bar issue where the canvas is detecting the commandbar but at its expanded height
- the canvas thinks the status bar is still there so doesnt expand but is automatically moved up
- the canvas just isnt set correctly

its been driving me crazy can someone please help
thanks

[How The App Is Affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DslLA.png)

---

### Update

```
     canvas.height = double.NaN
```

Does Nothing

```
     var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
     canvas.height = (cavas.height + statusBar.OccludedRect.Height); 
     await statusBar.HideAsync();
```

Does Nothing

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the DesiredBoundsMode?

```
ApplicationView.SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindows);
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, nope nothing worked so I gave up, I decided to use the status bar by changing the requested theme in app.xaml.cs and then changing the foreground colour in mainpage.cs